# exp.exe command not complete . it is showing in progress

Tags: c#, oracle

```
private void RunExportCommand()
    {            
        try
        {
            appLogger.WriteLog("RunExportCommand Method.");
            appLogger.WriteLog("Starting exporting data to dump file.");
            using (Process processExp = new Process())
            {
                string fileName = "exp.exe";
                processExp.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;                   
                processExp.StartInfo.Arguments = GetCommandString();                  
                processExp.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                processExp.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                processExp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                processExp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
                processExp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                appLogger.WriteLog("Before Start");
                processExp.Start();
                appLogger.WriteLog("After Start");
                appLogger.WriteLog("Started exporting data to dump file.");
                processExp.StandardInput.AutoFlush = true;                 
                processExp.StandardInput.Close();
                appLogger.WriteLog("Before WaitForExit");
               processExp.WaitForExit(Int32.MaxValue);
                appLogger.WriteLog("After WaitForExit");
            }
            appLogger.WriteLog("Successfully exported data to dump file.");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            appLogger.WriteLog("Exception while exporting data. " + e.ToString());
            throw new Exception("Exception while exporting data.", e);
        }
    }
```

In this code `processExp.WaitForExit(Int32.MaxValue)` line are not execute, but before that file lines are working. If I'm using created `filename.txt(log)` to *copy* or *move* it is showing lick error

**"Error occurred in IsErrorOccurred System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:MyBKP\BAK_01_01062017.txt' because it is being used by another process."**

Comment: Two questions:  1) What is `appLogger`?  2) Why are you redirecting standard input?

Comment: compiler display appLogger message in one notepad file , and appLogger.WriteLog("Before WaitForExit"); log are come but after log are note come because processExp.WaitForExit(Int32.MaxValue) not execute. this is waiting for completing the process.